# Create chart from Json data Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, charts, bar-chart

Hey I have a File json as you see in the image (1) I want to create a chart Like this (the second image) using javascript ( any library) how I can do simply ? I want a an example of code simple

[image: image 1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 6):

[ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com) would also work for this use case. Here is an example:

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: "bar", 
    "scale-x":{
    "values":[
      "ahbass marrakech",
      "massira 1 marrakech",
      "rue laayoune marrakech"
      ]
  },
 series : [
  {
   values : [2,1,1]
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
  ZC.LICENSE = ["569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9","ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d"];</script>
 <!--Inject End-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

In addition, you may find this [comparison of JavaScript charting frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks) helpful when considering your options.

Full disclosure: I'm on the ZingChart team. Please let me know if you have any questions about the quick demo.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [CanvasJS](http://canvasjs.com).

Here is an example of rendering chart from external json file.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataPoints = [];
  $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/45rin", function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= result.dataPoints.length - 1; i++) {
      dataPoints.push({
        label: result.dataPoints[i].label,
        y: parseInt(result.dataPoints[i].y)
      });
    }

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      data: [{
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: dataPoints
      }]
    });

    chart.render();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) is a good chart/graphing tool for JavaScript if you are just getting started. Here is an example that I created when I was first looking into chart/graphing libraries in JS.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Age', 'Weight'],
                    [8,   12],
                    [4,   5.5],
                    [11,  14],
                    [4,   5],
                    [3,   3.5],
                    [6.5, 7],
                ]);

                var options = {
                    title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
                    hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
                    vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
                    legend: 'none'
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart" sytle="width:900px;height:500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which produces the following chart.
[image: Google Chart demo screen shot]

You can use the `JSON.parse` to get the data out of the JSON file instead of hard coding the data like in my example.